# Unable to resolve symbol: thrown?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

What is the proper way to do the following in clojure?

```
(ns todo.test.models.task
  (:use [clojure.test]))

(deftest main-test
  (is (thrown? Exception (throw Exception "stuff")))
  (is (not (thrown? Exception (+ 2 3))))
)
```

First testcase runs fine but the whole snippet returns "Unable to resolve symbol: thrown?"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`is` is a macro that looks for the symbol `thrown?` in its body and build tests. 
**`thrown?` is not actually a function you can call.** The default behaviour of `is` fails the test if an exception is thrown that was not beeing looked for, so you can just remove the `(not (thrown?` from the above example and get the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

`thrown?` is a special assertion that must show up after `is`, so you can't nest it in other expressions, so in the context of the `is` macro, the second assertion will not understand the symbol thrown?.

You could just say:

```
(deftest main-test
  (is (thrown? Exception (throw (Exception. "stuff"))))
  (is (= 5 (+ 2 3))))
```

If an exception is thrown in (+ 2 3), clojure.test will report 1 :error and 0 :fail and dump the stack trace.

Also note that your `(throw Exception "stuff")` is incorrect - you need to construct the Exception correctly inside the throw.

Answer (score 0):

Use `doseq` if you want to do it for many statements:

```clj
(testing "bla"
    (doseq [x [1 2 3 4]]
      (my-dangerous-func! x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but..
In addition to the above answers, if you really want a `not-thrown?` assertion, you can extend the `is` macro by adding your own e.g.

```clojure
(defmethod assert-expr 'not-thrown? [msg form]
  ;; (is (not-thrown? c expr))
  ;; Asserts that evaluating expr does not throws an exception of class c.
  ;; Returns the exception thrown.
  (let [klass (second form)
        body (nthnext form 2)]
    `(try ~@body
          (do-report {:type :pass, :message ~msg,
                      :expected '~form, :actual nil})
          (catch ~klass e#
            (do-report {:type :fail, :message ~msg,
                        :expected '~form, :actual e#})
            e#))))
```

This should then work as your original expectations

```clojure
((deftest main-test
   (is (thrown? Exception (throw (Exception. "stuff"))))
   (is (not-thrown? Exception (+ 2 3)))))
```

However, please note that `clojure.test` will always report an error if an exception occurs in your function but if you have a special use-case for this, there you go.